# How to create a header in a flat file using MuleSoft?

Tags: dataweave, fixed-width

I have a question regarding transforming JSON to Flat file. I have successfully come up with an output in flat file format however, it is hard for me to create a header to identify the name per column and a trailer.

Flat file output

[image]

JSON output

[image]

Fields per column

[image]

FFD Schema

[image]

Comment: Hi, instead of so many screenshots it strongly recommended to post in text form, to be able to copy and search. That increases the chances of getting a response.

Answer (score 0):

The Flatfile format doesn't has a header. As an alternative you could add another structure for the header, with a single record, before the data records.